# How to install jmathplot.jar and use it in Java?

Tags: java, jar

I need to install the following library in order to use it in Java, however I do not know how to do, could you please help me? (I am relatively new to Java)

jmathplot.jar
jmatharray.jar
website:
https://code.google.com/p/jmatharray/
https://code.google.com/p/jmathplot/

I tried to do the following but none has worked so far:
-run the .jar files with java with the command prompt, this option did not work because "java could not find main class"
-put the file in the project directory
-put the file in the library directory

what am I doing wrong?
thank you

Comment: do you use any ide ?

Comment: Yes I use Eclipse Luna

Comment: If you already have an Eclipse project, Right click on Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path.  Select Libraries Tab and Click button "Add External Jars"...Browse to the path where these Jars are.  If you are running command line, copy all these jars in the current directory and use `java -cp . SomeMain`. Make sure SomeMain is also in the CLASSPATH

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add any jar in java, you need to add it to the class path.
Usually to use the API's provided in the jar, you need to ensure that the jar is available via the class path during compilation, as well as run time.

See javac: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html
See java : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html